# Unity: How would I create the graphics for some elements in C++ to be used by Unity?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, directx

First, I know that the 'proper' answer is to just port everything to C#. Please don't bother posting that answer. That's the long-term goal. I don't need to hear it restated.

I have a game I'd like to port to Unity on PC (initially.) It has a very heavy user interface. I'm wondering how I would go about creating the graphics for the UI in C++? My game currently uses GDI to create the dialogs, each in its own buffer, then BitBlts to the screen.

In a 'perfect world' I'd like to try passing those buffers to Unity which would then display them and pass any mouse/gesture events back to C++ for processing. It's a kludge, but much faster than porting everything and would let me do some prototype/testing to see if it's practical. I could then port the screens one at a time to Unity or port the UI Library I wrote.

I did see one post which talked about doing something a little similar where the C++ pushed textures into OpenGL where Unity would then render them. Are there any articles which discuss how to do this on a PC using DirectX before I start hacking away?

It sounds simple, but I'd appreciate some pointers on interfacing between them. The documentation on the unity site is a bit sparse on the details of the interface.

Clarification: My question is really about what I need to do with DirectX in C++ to send a texture back. Do I need to initialize DirectX in C++ as well as Unity, do I need to pass a display handle or something else to C++ along with the texture handle, etc.? Is it as easy as just calling the C++ routine to return the texture? I'm familiar both with how to talk between C# and C++ and how 3D engines work in general, I need to populate a DirectX texture from an HDC and somehow pass that data back to Unity for Display.

Ralph

Comment: Calling native code from C# usually involves something called `pinvoke`, I believe there is some support in Mono.

Comment: Thanks, I understand about P/Invoke, my question is really about what I need to do with DirectX in C++ to send a texture back. Do I need to initialize DirectX in C++, do I need to pass a display handle or something else to C++ along with the texture handle, etc.?

Comment: I somehow doubt Unity's native render pipeline is that extendable...

Comment: Actually, It looks like it is that extensible. I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, a starting point at least. I should have RTFMed the manual better, my bad.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePluginInterface.html

refers to this project

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/graphicsdemos/src/default/NativeRenderingPlugin/

I hope this helps someone else.